# Visual Studio Code two html element editing problem

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide

i am a complete beginner to vs code and i want using it to edit my html file but somehow now it is showing two editing cursors on identical tag . this is the image of it

[image: This is the image]

Comment: Please close vs-code and open it again.

Comment: did you tried esc button ?

Comment: i tried restarting vscode and my computer and also the esc works but if i click on any other thing it again do the same thing .